# Android Google Maps to remove the last added polygon line

Tags: android, google-maps

Added the Google Maps into the Android application. Draw the polygonlines using the method given by the Google.I just need to remove the last drawn polygon line.
I tried with the following codes.
Polyline polyline;

```
ArrayList<Polyline> polylines = new ArrayList<Polyline>();
```

This code for the click event to delete the last drawn polygon line.

```
for (Polyline line : polylines) {
    if (polylines.get(polylines.size() - 1).equals(line)) {
          line.remove();
          polylines.remove(line);
          }
       }
```

if i put the following code i.e

```
polyline.remove()
```

This remove entire polygon lines.I just need only to remove the last added polygon line.Please give me solution..

Answer (score 1):

simply one line of code:

```
polylines.remove(polylines.size() - 1)
```

Comment: I used the above code but it reduce the length of the ArrayList<Polyline> polylines but it doesn't reflect on the Google Maps the last line is available.

Answer (score 0):

Use following lines

```
polylines.remove(polylines.get(polylines.size()-1));
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used gmaps in java, but in js there is a method called removeAt(). It was something like

`polyline.getPath().removeAt(lines - 1);`

where lines is the number of lines the polyline contains (Integer), but I'm not sure if the android api has that method. It's worth a try though.